# Is there a way to find the position of a duplicate window?

Tags: c, winapi, coordinates

I'm making a game of checkers, and I was able to create the windows properly. However, I did so using a loop, since I didn't wanna make 64 different windows.

Here's the loop:

```
k = 1;
    for (y = 0; y < 8; y++)
{
    
    // This is the x value used in window creation
    BoardSquareLocX = 100;
    for (x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    {
        
        // This alternates which window, red or black, will be shown next
        switch (k)
        {
        case 0:
            k = 1;

            // This is the same thing as the black window
            BoardSquareRedWindowCreate(hwnd);                
            break;

        case 1:
            k = 0;
            BoardSquareBlackWindowCreate(hwnd);      
            break;      
        }
        BoardSquareLocX += 60;
    }

    
    // This is just to alternate which square, red or black, it makes at the beginning of the row
    switch (k)
    {
    case 0:
        k = 1;
        break;
    case 1:
        k = 0;
        break;
    }
    
    // This is the y value used in window creation
    BoardSquareLocY += 60;
}
```

Here's the black square window. It's just a button for now.

```
BoardSquareBlackWindowCreate(hwnd)
{

Board_Square_Black_Window = CreateWindowExW(
    0,
    L"Button",
    L"",
    WS_CHILDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
    BoardSquareLocX, BoardSquareLocY, 50, 50,
    hwnd, (HMENU)4, NULL, NULL);

}
```

The (HMENU)4 thing does this:

```
        switch(wParam)
 {

        case 4:
        GetWindowRect(Board_Square_Black_Window, &rect); // rect is defined

        fprintf(fp, "\nTop:    %d", (rect.top));
        fprintf(fp, "\nLeft:   %d", (rect.left));
        fprintf(fp, "\nBottom: %d", (rect.bottom));
        fprintf(fp, "\nRight:  %d", (rect.right));

 }
```

The values are the same no matter which button I click on. For example, if I start up the program and click on every single button, The rect.top will be the same for each one, rect.left will be the same, and so on.

My goal is to get the positions of all of the individual buttons, even if they have the same handle. Is that possible?

I am very stuck so if you help me, I'll give you a good noodle star.

Also tell me if I'm dumb, it helps

Comment: Multiple windows can't have the same handle. You are using 1 variable to track all black windows, but only the last window created will be referred to by that variable. I assume you are doing the same for the red windows, too. Don't do that. Save the window handles in an array, and use the array indexes as the window IDs. Or just use the window handle that the click message gives you in its lparam.

Comment: You can get the clicked position through the mouse click event and [GetCursorPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcursorpos) api, and then compare the clicked coordinate information with the button position to determine which part you clicked.

Comment: @SongZhu-MSFT that is a bit overkill, considering mouse events and button click events tell you which window is being clicked.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, that is a better way, but OP does not want to create different windows.

Comment: @SongZhu-MSFT in that case, a single window with colored boxes drawn on it in WM_PAINT, and mouse events that directly calculate the clicked box, will suffice. No need to involve GetCursorPos() or comparisons hunting for the box

Comment: @RemyLebeau Will I still have to save the positions of each box, since there is only one window?
Edit: Also, if I use array indexes as window id's, don't they have to be defined as handles? Or is there another way to "talk" to the windows?

Comment: @PupperGump a checkers board uses fixed-sized boxes. You don't need to store the positions at all, since you can just calculate those values using just an index. The only thing you would need to store is which checker is located at each index. No, you don't (and can't) define indexes as handles.